# No compiler is provided in this environment. When execute mvn clean package

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Hi when I run on my cmd the command

> mvn clean package

I get a compiler error: No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

But I checked out my PATH, JAVA_HOME and HOME_M2[image]
[image]
[image]

I also checked the Installed JREs in Eclipse:
[image]

Apparently everything is ok, any ideas about why do I'm getting that error? Thanks!

Comment: one thing I found weird is why its showing JRE7u65 if you have installed jdk8u40 ?

Comment: the problem is in your PATH; replace the jre directory declared there with your jdk directory. Also note that whatever setting you have in eclipse, it will affecting launching from the ide, not what happens using cmd line

Comment: Add jdk bin to your path , It will solve the issue.Setting Jdk Home is just not enough'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that in your `PATH` is only a JRE, not a JDK.

[image: highlighted path]

You have to include the JDK into your `PATH`, then maven will find it.

Answer (score 1):

https://roufid.com/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment/

Do set your JAVA_HOME.

```
export JAVA_HOME=path_to_jdk
```

try again